# Question on indefinite article (in couple weeks or in a couple weeks)

Tags: idioms, indefinite-articles

I have a question on indefinite articles.
I thought **a** is only used with singular nouns, by definition.

Why is "in a couple weeks" the right way? Isn't a couple weeks more than one?
I thought it would be "in couple weeks" but I see everywhere that it's used as "in a couple weeks". Can someone please be kind and explain why this is so?

Comment: The idiom is ***a** couple (of) weeks*. The _of_ is optional, but the _a_ is required. And you're making a terrible mistake, paying attention to definitions of grammatical words. Definitions are not grammar; grammar is what people actually say, not some incorrect and incomplete definitions that a writer put in a textbook. They are virtually always wrong. Listen to what people say, and pay no attention to those definitions.

Comment: You forgot an article in front of *right way*.

Comment: I would say "in a couple of weeks", though it might come through as "in a coupla weeks".

Comment: We Americans tend to swallow our syllables, so I would not be surprised if that is the source of the idiom.

Comment: The 'of' is required in British English. _A couple weeks_ is distinctly American, and sounds Yiddish-inspired to me.

Comment: @ColinFine - I'm pretty sure that if you listened closely you would usually hear the American speaker saying "coupla" if the separate and distinct "of" was absent.

Comment: @HotLicks: yes, I agree that it is often _coupla_. COCA has 473 instances of _a couple weeks_, as against 6 for _a coupla weeks_ and 2354 for _a couple of weeks_. It's no surprise that _a coupla_ doesn't get many hits in this written corpus, and some of the _a couple weeks_ may actually represent this, but I don't believe that the majority are.

Comment: The corresponding numbers for the BNC are 2 _a couple weeks_, 1 for _a coupla weeks_, 427 for _a couple of week_.

Comment: @ColinFine - It would be rare to see "coupla" written, though it is often spoken.  Unless someone is being very attentive to the dialect, it would almost always be transcribed as "couple" or "couple of", usually with the transcriber not giving it a second thought.

Comment: @HotLicks: Certainly, but I think it's unlikely they'd transcribe it as _a couple_ rather than _a couple of_.

Comment: @ColinFine - Probably not, because they would "hear" "couple of".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **idiom** "*a couple weeks*" the indefinite article "*a*" modifies the singular noun "*couple*" according to the rule of indefinite articles.

> Another example:
>
> My wife and I are ***a*** *couple*.

As @John Lawler so aptly pointed out, the confusion is in the missing (yet still implied) preposition "*of*" that creates the **illusion** that "*a*" is modifying the plural "weeks". That would leave "*couple*" as an orphan in the phrase. *Couple* is not generally used as an adjective, and it couldn't correctly be used as an adjective in this case.

Idiom tends to defy grammar, but there is often a correct grammatical form supporting the idiom in its etymology.

Answer (score 0):

"A couple weeks" does indeed sound incorrect because it should correctly be written as "a couple **of** weeks". It makes perfect sense if it is written or spoken correctly because in this case the "couple of weeks" becomes a singular group of weeks consisting of two weeks. It's like saying "a flock of geese" which is a singular flock consisting of many geese, or similarly "a pair of socks" which is a single pair of socks.

If said incorrectly missing the "of" the way many Americans do the whole sentence sounds odd.